# replace cell in dataframe if it contains a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to replace every cell in a python dataframe if it contains the string p.

```
A    B   C 
150  5   5p
10   4   8p
1    20  10
```

to make it look like

```
A    B   C 
150  5   None
10   4   None
1    20  10
```

I tried it with

```
df.replace(df['C'] == df['C'].str.contains('d'), value =None)
```

which didnt work, can someone tell me why it didnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[150, 10, 1], "B":[5,4,20], "C":["5p", "8p", 10]})

df.applymap(lambda x: float(str(x).replace("p","")))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
       A     B     C
0  150.0   5.0   5.0
1   10.0   4.0   8.0
2    1.0  20.0  10.0
```

**FOLLOW UP**

Following the comment by @n1colas.m, this is the approach if you want `None` instead of a number parsing:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: None if "p" in str(x) else x)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
     A   B     C
0  150   5   NaN
1   10   4   NaN
2    1  20  10.0
```

or

```
df.applymap(lambda x: "None" if "p" in str(x) else x)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
     A   B     C
0  150   5  None
1   10   4  None
2    1  20    10
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that the OP is trying to replace the string by `None`, not the numeric part of it. But clearly this is just a minor adaptation from your code.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for thanks